# Trigger / sync drum beat / drum machine to MIDI keyboard bass line

Tags: drums, keyboard

I play a bass line with my left hand, melody with my right and chords between the two. I want to add in drum beats triggered and synced to my left hand bass. For example, if I play C-E-G-D-F#-A-C-E-G I might want a kick when I play the Cs and Ds a snare when I play the other notes. However, if I then play C-C-C I might want three kicks. Then I might want to turn the drums off for a bit, then back on. Obviously mapping a kick to C and D doesn’t work very well because C and D are in other chords / peggios. I accept that the drums might take one bar to sync. I think I could code this on a laptop with some difficulty, but is there an app or box I can buy that will do this?